# Unzip a bunch of zips into their own directories

Tags: linux, compression

I have a bunch of zip files I want to unzip in Linux into their own directory. For example:

a1.zip a2.zip b1.zip b2.zip

would be unzipped into:

a1 a2 b1 b2

respectively. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

`for x in *.zip; do unzip -d "$(basename "$x" .zip)" "$x"; done`

Comment: Or, with ghostdog74's advice: `for x in *.zip; do unzip -d "${x%.zip}" "$x"; done`

Answer (score 4):

no need to use external basename

```
for file in *zip
do
 unzip -d "${file%.zip}" "$file"
done
```